# wordpress admin (wp-admin) can not access

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have upload my wordpress website on live server and front end is loading perfectly fine.

While i login to my admin by http://www.my-site.com/wp-admin it not loading login page and display error like, redirected you too many times.

I can load login page by below URL,

```
http://www.my-site.com/wp-login.php
```

and can load login form, but after proving credential it can not redirecting me to dashboard and again display same error like,redirected you too many times.

I have done all available solution like,

1) check site url in wp_option table : its proper

2) delete .htaccess file from root and upload fresh

3) disable plugins and check and enable agian but not working.

Can anyone help me what is wrong in my case and how to enable wp-admin and can access admin?

Comment: your server working on apache? or nginx?

Comment: it is apache server.

Comment: maybe asking the obvious, but have you also deleted .htaccess (if present) from wp-admin dir?